# Python Web Scraping SSLError: Bad handshake

Tags: python, ssl, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm new to programming - especially webscraping issues regarding SSL/TSL certificates, so please don't butcher me aha!

Right, so...

The script I've written works on my Mac (OS X El Capitan 10.11.15) flawlessly, it is essentially scraping a few numbers here and there off of a website with a login. The problem arises when I attempt to run the program on my two other computers running Windows 7 64 bit and Windows 10 32 bit. I have a basic understanding of handshakes and SSL but not enough to figure out what's going on here.

The website I'm trying to access has a bit of a certificate problem (chrome won't let you visit it, but Mozilla and Safari do), however I've always gotten round this by using the verify=False argument of request.Session().get(....). By the way at the top of the program I have:

```
 with requests.Session() as c:
```

in case line 179 is a bit confusing.

I have this at the beginning of the script too (though hashtagging it out makes no difference):

```
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS += ':RC4-SHA'
```

Here is the complete traceback:

```
SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\indy_\Desktop\bk_programs\var.py in <module>()
    226 hh_saleslist, hh_settleinvlist = hh_scraper()
    227 tillster_webvals = tillster_puller()
--> 228 sicom_report_esg, sicom_report_cor, sicom_report_nor, sicom_report_gry, sicom_report_bst = sicom_scraper()
    229 
    230 

C:\Users\indy_\Desktop\bk_programs\var.py in sicom_scraper()
    177         for i in range(len(ips)):
    178             # Retrieve the CSRF token first
--> 179             soup = BeautifulSoup(c.get(login_urllist[i], verify=False).content, 'html.parser')
    180             csrftoken = soup.find('input', dict(name='XXX_login_token'))['value']
    181 

C:\Users\indy_\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.pyc in get(self, url, **kwargs)
    485 
    486         kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
--> 487         return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
    488 
    489     def options(self, url, **kwargs):

C:\Users\indy_\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.pyc in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    473         }
    474         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 475         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    476 
    477         return resp

C:\Users\indy_\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.pyc in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    583 
    584         # Send the request
--> 585         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    586 
    587         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

C:\Users\indy_\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.pyc in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    475         except (_SSLError, _HTTPError) as e:
    476             if isinstance(e, _SSLError):
--> 477                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    478             elif isinstance(e, ReadTimeoutError):
    479                 raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)

SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')],)",)
```

I am aware that there are other posts similar to mine but I cannot seem to get any to work. I'd really appreciate if anyone could point out my mistakes or send me in the direction of some documentation that'd help.

PS. I'm running Python 2.7.11.

Thank you

**Edit - more info**

The URL in question is https://81.137.196.234/~sicom/mgrng/login.php

and a list of all modules installed:

'-registry-path==1.0', 'appinst==2.1.5', 'apptools==4.4.0', 'atom==0.3.10', 'backports-abc==0.4', 'beautifulsoup4==4.4.1', 'beautifulsoup==3.2.1', 'casuarius==1.1', 'catalyst==1.0.2', 'certifi==2016.2.28', 'cffi==1.7.0', 'chaco==4.5.0', 'chardet==2.3.0', 'codetools==4.2.0', 'configobj==5.0.6', 'configparser==3.5.0', 'cryptography==1.5', 'cycler==0.10.0', 'decorator==4.0.9', 'distribute-remove==1.0.0', 'docutils==0.12', 'enable==4.5.1', 'enaml==0.9.8', 'enclosure==0.4.3', 'encore==0.6.0', 'enstaller==4.8.12', 'entrypoints==0.2.2', 'envisage==4.5.1', 'examples==7.3', 'faulthandler==2.4', 'flake8==2.5.1', 'futures==3.0.3', 'html5lib==0.999', 'humanize==0.5.1', 'idle==2.7.3', 'idna==2.1', 'ipaddress==1.0.16', 'ipykernel==4.3.1', 'ipython-genutils==0.1.0', 'ipython4==4.1.2', 'ipython==4.0.0', 'ipywidgets==5.1.5', 'jinja2==2.8', 'jsonschema==2.4.0', 'jupyter-client==4.2.2', 'jupyter-console==4.1.1', 'jupyter-core==4.1.0', 'jupyter==1.0.0', 'kernmagic==0.2.0', 'kiwisolver==0.1.3', 'libopenjpeg==2.1.0', 'libpng==1.6.12', 'libsodium==1.0.3', 'lxml==3.6.0', 'markupsafe==0.23', 'matplotlib==1.5.1', 'mccabe==0.3.1', 'memory-profiler==0.41', 'mistune==0.7.1', 'mkl-service==1.0', 'mkl==11.1.4', 'mpmath==0.19', 'nbconvert==4.2.0', 'nbformat==4.0.1', 'ndg-httpsclient==0.4.2', 'nose==1.3.7', 'notebook==4.2.1', 'numpy==1.10.4', 'pandas==0.18.0', 'path.py==8.1.1', 'pep8==1.7.0', 'pexpect==2.4', 'pickleshare==0.5', 'pil-remove==1.0.0', 'pillow==3.2.0', 'pip==8.1.2', 'plotly==1.9.10', 'ply==3.8', 'psutil==3.3.0', 'pyaudio==0.2.4', 'pycparser==2.14', 'pycrypto==2.6.1', 'pyface==5.1.0', 'pyflakes==1.1.0', 'pyglet==1.1.4', 'pygments==2.1.3', 'pyopenssl==16.1.0', 'pyparsing==2.0.3', 'pyreadline==2.1', 'python-dateutil==2.5.2', 'pytz==2016.3', 'pywin32==220', 'pyzmq==15.2.0', 'qtconsole==4.2.1', 'scipy==0.17.1', 'setuptools==23.1.0', 'simplegeneric==0.8.1', 'singledispatch==3.4.0.3', 'six==1.10.0', 'ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2', 'sympy==1.0', 'tornado==4.3', 'traitlets==4.2.1', 'traits-enaml==0.2.1', 'traits==4.5.0', 'traitsui==5.1.0', 'urllib3==1.16', 'wxpython==3.0.2.0', 'xlwt==1.1.2'

```
>>> ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
'OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016'
```

**2nd edit following on from Steffen's comment**

```
import requests
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS += ':RC4-SHA' 
with requests.Session() as c:

    url = "https://81.137.196.234/~sicom/mgrng/login.php"
    page = c.get(url, verify=False)
    print page.content
```

and the traceback is:

```
SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\indy_\appdata\local\temp\tmpkuleyd.py in <module>()
      6 
      7     url = "https://81.137.196.234/~sicom/mgrng/login.php"
----> 8     page = c.get(url, verify=False)
      9     print page.content
     10 

C:\Users\indy_\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.pyc in get(self, url, **kwargs)
    485 
    486         kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
--> 487         return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
    488 
    489     def options(self, url, **kwargs):

C:\Users\indy_\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.pyc in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    473         }
    474         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 475         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    476 
    477         return resp

C:\Users\indy_\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.pyc in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    583 
    584         # Send the request
--> 585         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    586 
    587         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

C:\Users\indy_\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.pyc in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    475         except (_SSLError, _HTTPError) as e:
    476             if isinstance(e, _SSLError):
--> 477                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    478             elif isinstance(e, ReadTimeoutError):
    479                 raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)

SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')],)",)
```

I don't need to go through and actually verify the certificate - I know it's safe. I actually just want to bypass the certification checks, which is what i thought the verify=False argument does in requests.get() but apparently it is being ignored.

[what chrome says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQtzy.png)

**Solved**

Did a full uninstall of Python and all extra modules.

Reinstalled Python 2.7.11. and now it spits out many

```
C:\Users\indy_\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:821: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
```

InsecureRequestWarning)

errors, but works, thankfully.

Comment: This is not enough information to reproduce the problem and help. Please provide the domain name from the URL and the openssl version in use (`ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION` from within python)

Comment: I've edited the post, please comment if you need more info, thank you for the quick response by the way :)

Comment: strange: could you please do a minimal example, i.e. `requests.get('https://81.137.196.234', verify=False)`? And the cipher setting  with RC4-SHA added is essential for this host.

Comment: As above, exactly the same error

Comment: That's strange. It works for me with openssl 1.0.2.h. What I could imagine: your openssl is build without support for RC4 (unlikely). There is some firewall blocking the connection, either on  your system or in your  network. Did you try to access the site from the same system with another tool?

Comment: No, it appears I can't access this site through either chome, mozzila or ie from this system. Strange. Do you think it's worth me trying to change to openssl 1.0.2.h?

Comment: ie says 

"Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings and try connecting to https://81.137.196.234  again. If this error persists, it is possible that this site uses an unsupported protocol or cipher suite such as RC4 (link for the details), which is not considered secure. Please contact your site administrator."

They're all turned on, and SSL 3.0.

Comment: Looks like all of these browsers have disabled RC4 for security reasons. But this is the only cipher supported by this (broken) website.  If you have the openssl binary you might try to connect from the computer with `openssl s_client -connect 81.137.196.234:443 -cipher RC4-SHA` and see if this works.

Comment: I understand what you're getting at. How exactly would I go about doing that? straight into a python terminal? also, so you think it's definitely the version of openssl i'm using? the mac that the program works on is using openssl 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016.

Comment: `openssl` is a stand alone command which may or may be not on your system (usually it is on any UNIX systems but usually not on Windows). I don't think it is related to the version of openssl you are using since it works for me with the next patch level and there were no major changes.  Thus my guess is that it is something special to your system which is not on my system and not on your Mac, i.e. some firewall blocking the connection. A packet capture (wireshark) might be helpful to narrow down the problem too.

Comment: hmmm I shall keep investigating....it is especially annoying as it did used to work on the windows 10 machine but for some reason had stopped....I shall keep investigating... thank you for your help thus far